# Relative cost of texture lookups to branching

Tags: hlsl

When looking for information on best practices in shader coding I'm coming up empty on matters of performance and why or even if certain techniques are better than others. More specifically, branching vs texture lookups. In Shader Model 3 with Dynamic Flow Control it's supposedly efficient to branch when the output is texels close together but I don't really have any specifics to support the threshold of when to or when not to do it. So my question is, what is the relative cost of a texture lookup to that of an instance of branching? When does the branching get unrolled (if I'm using that term right) and run through all the possibilities so as to make it inefficient?

I've included some example code here as well, though I'm more interested in the theory rather than the example's specifics.

```
    // Is something like this faster:

    float4 final;

    float4 t1 = tex2D(_Tex1, IN.uv_Tex1);
    float4 t2 = tex2D(_Tex2, IN.uv_Tex2);

    final = lerp(t1, t2, smoothstep(-1, 1, IN.worldPos.y));

    // Or this:

    float final;

    if (IN.worldPos.y < -1)
    {
        final = tex2D(_Tex1, IN.uv_Tex1);
    }
    else if (IN.worldPos.y > 1)
    {
        final = tex2D(_Tex2, IN.uv_Tex2);
    }
    else
    {
        final = lerp(tex2D(_Tex1, IN.uv_Tex1),
                        tex2D(_Tex2, IN.uv_Tex2), 
                        smoothstep(-1, 1, IN.worldPos.y));
    }

    // And would it be the same if they were more complex lookups:

    float4 t1 = (tex2D(_Tex1, mul(rot, IN.uv_Tex1*0.5))
                +tex2D(_Tex1, IN.uv_Tex1))*0.5;
    float4 t2 = (tex2D(_Tex2, mul(rot, IN.uv_Tex2*0.5))
                +tex2D(_Tex2, IN.uv_Tex2))*0.5;

    // What is the relative cost of branching to texture lookups?
```

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on your GPU architecture, but generally texture lookups are several times slower than dynamic branching.